# sed to ignore a pattern as well as match a pattern in same line

Tags: sed

Input file

```
<a href="perl.html">perl</a>     <a href="http://zoidberg.sourceforge.net/out.html">http://zoidberg.sourceforge.net</a>
<a href="zoiduser.html">zoiduser</a>    <a href="perl.html">perl</a>     <a href="http://zoidberg.sourceforge.net/sample.html">http://zoidberg.sourceforge.net</a>
```

I need to only remove .HTML extension from below URL from above file:

```
<a href="perl.html">perl</a>
<a href="zoiduser.html">zoiduser</a>
```

So that the final output should look like:

```
<a href="perl">perl</a>     <a href="http://zoidberg.sourceforge.net/out.html">http://zoidberg.sourceforge.net</a>
<a href="zoiduser">zoiduser</a>    <a href="perl.html">perl</a>     <a href="http://zoidberg.sourceforge.net/sample.html">http://zoidberg.sourceforge.net</a>
```

This is what I am doing:

```
sed '/"http\|"www\|"mailto/ ! s|\(.html\)||g' file
```

But it ignores the line as soon as it matches the first pattern i.e. avoid URLs that start with "http|"www|"mailto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -E 's/("(http|www|mailto)[^"]*")|\.html/\1/g' file
```

*Details*:

- `-E` - enables POSIX ERE syntax
- `("(http|www|mailto)[^"]*")` - Group 1 (`\1`): `"` and then either `http`, `www`, or `mailto` and then zero or more chars other than `"` and then a `"`
- `|` - or
- `\.html` - `.html` string.

The replacement is Group 1 values.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/KmLUHI):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='<a href="perl.html">perl</a>     <a href="http://zoidberg.sourceforge.net/out.html">http://zoidberg.sourceforge.net</a>
<a href="zoiduser.html">zoiduser</a>    <a href="perl.html">perl</a>     <a href="http://zoidberg.sourceforge.net/sample.html">http://zoidberg.sourceforge.net</a>'
sed -E 's/("(http|www|mailto)[^"]*")|\.html/\1/g' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
<a href="perl">perl</a>     <a href="http://zoidberg.sourceforge.net/out.html">http://zoidberg.sourceforge.net</a>
<a href="zoiduser">zoiduser</a>    <a href="perl">perl</a>     <a href="http://zoidberg.sourceforge.net/sample.html">http://zoidberg.sourceforge.net</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not recommended to parse HTML using shell utilities like sed, awk, perl etc. But if you really have to use negation of certain keywords then I would suggest this `perl`:

```sh
perl -pe 's/"(?!www|http|mailto)([^"]+)\.html/"\1/g' f.html

<a href="perl">perl</a>     <a href="http://zoidberg.sourceforge.net/out.html">http://zoidberg.sourceforge.net</a>
<a href="zoiduser">zoiduser</a>    <a href="perl">perl</a>     <a href="http://zoidberg.sourceforge.net/sample.html">http://zoidberg.sourceforge.net</a>
```

`(?!www|http|mailto)` is negative lookahead to fail the match if these keywords appear just after `"`

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples only, please try following `awk` code. Simple explanation would be, checking if line contains `<a href="(http|mailto|www):` in line and if this condition is TRUE then using `sub` function to substitute first .html" occurrence with `">` and then print that line, next will skip printing lines where conditions are not met. `1` will print lines where conditions are not met.

```
awk '/<a href="(http|mailto|www):/ && sub(/.html">/,"\">"){print;next} 1' Input_file
```